# If $P_I$ is a parabolic subgroup in $GL_n(k)$, is $P_I$ conjugate to ${P_I}^-$ under some element of $W$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, coxeter-groups

Suppose $P_I$ is a standard parabolic subgroup of $GL_n(k)$ (we can assume $k$ is finite, but I doubt it matters). Is $P_I$ conjugate to the opposite parabolic ${P_I}^-$ under some element of the Weyl group $W$? Is it perhaps the longest element of the Weyl subgroup $W_I$?

I know in general it's not possible to conjugate a parabolic to its opposite, but I wonder if it's at least possible for $GL_n(k)$? If it is true, a reference would be sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is no. See the answers for the MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62471/can-every-parabolic-subgroup-be-conjugated-to-its-opposite-by-an-element-of-the